# JavaScript - Function returning twice

Tags: javascript, function

I don't know much about JavaScript, here is the code I have:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var x = 10

function startClock() {
    if (x !== ' ') {
        x = x - 1
        document.frm.clock.value = x
        setTimeout("startClock()", 1000)
    }
    if (x == 0) {
        x = ' ';
        document.frm.clock.value = x;
        success.location.href = "success.php";
    }
}
</script>
<body onLoad(startClock);>
```

affected iframe:

```
<input name="clock" size="3" readonly="readonly"

<iframe name="success" src="blank.htm"></iframe>
```

when the timer counts down, success.php is loaded twice. I know thise because 1.)It inserts data into my DB twice, 2.)I can actually see the loading symbol in the tab reloading a second.

When I change the function to something like:

```
 <script language="JavaScript">

var x = 10
var y = 1

function startClock() {
    if (x !== 'Fin') {
        x = x - y
        document.frm.clock.value = x
        setTimeout("startClock()", 1000)
    }
    if (x == 0) {
        x = 'Fin';
        document.frm.clock.value = x;
        success.location.href = "success.php";
    }
}

</script>
```

...the page is only loaded once.

Can anyone tell me what is happening here? I also tried using '0' in place of ' ' and got the same double execution...

Comment: Changing your second `if` to and `else if` might solve your problem.

Comment: *"It inserts data into my DB twice."* Then you may need to fix your server page. `GET` operations must be [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) (sorry, not my word). For operations that *change* things, use `POST` or one of the other verbs. (The exception, in my opinion, being "visits" data.)

Comment: The first version of your question used the flag value `" "`. The current version uses `"Fin"`. Which is it? Oh, wait, it's back to `" "` again.

Comment: this was itching me for some reason `<body onload="startClock()">`

Answer (score 1):

In  Javascript there are TWO comparison operators:

"==" -- means equal to

"===" means "exactly equal to" -- which means that the value and the TYPE must be the same

I suspect (although I dind't bother to test the theory) that if you use "===" rather than "=="  in your original code you will find it works as you intended.  However, there are a number of things that need fixing -- 1) you are inconsistent with using ";", 2) the code should be structured to ensure that on any given iteration it can only "restart" the timer OR fire the sucess and NEVER both.  Here is a cleaner version:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
   // 10 iterations at 1 second intervals
   var x = 10;

   function startClock() {
     document.frm.clock.value = --x;
     if (x <= 0) {
       document.frm.clock.value = x;
       success.location.href = "success.php";
     } else {
       setTimeout("startClock()", 1000);
     }
   } // startClock
</script>
<body onLoad(startClock);>
```

Comment: +1 Nice answer. I think the second `document.frm.clock.value = x;` is superfluous though. Or maybe you meant `= ' ';`?

Comment: Yes, totally superluous -- just overlooked as I was moving stuff around -- in PHP 0 == '' is TRUE but 0 === '' is FALSE -- I know that the code quoted above is using ' ' (single blank rather than a null string) but the fact that when he changed his "sentinel" value from that to "Fin" it worked very much makes me think that's what's going on

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the '==' and '===' operators, something new learned. Thanks for the clean code, works great!

Comment: You're welcome -- as Tim pointed out the second assignment to document.frm.clock.value can be removed - take care

Comment: @user1142872: if Murray's answer solved the problem for you, you should mark it as accepted (there's a tick next to the answer score). Welcome again to stack overflow :)

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
if (x == 0) {  // note this is now first
    x = ' ';
    document.frm.clock.value = x;
    success.location.href = "success.php";
} else if (x !== ' ') { // note the else/if
    x = x - 1;
    document.frm.clock.value = x;
    setTimeout("startClock()", 1000)
}
```

Otherwise, when x is 1, a timeout for startClock() will be set, AND the location will be loaded. Then, the timeout will fire, loading the page again (since `x = ' '` and   `' ' == 0` returns true).

It is probably better practice to say:

```
if (x === 0) {  // note the ===
    x = ' ';
    document.frm.clock.value = x;
    success.location.href = "success.php";
} else if (x !== ' ') {
    x = x - 1;
    document.frm.clock.value = x;
    setTimeout("startClock()", 1000)
}
```

Because you don't need the truth conversion that `==` does for you.

---

Your example with `'Fin'` instead of `' '`  worked, because on the `startClock()` call after the location had been loaded, `x` was `'Fin'`, and `('Fin' == 0)` is false.

Comment: Just tried it, for some reason the else if statement is not being ran... The timer continues into the negative after it hits zero. It's as if x never equals 0???

Comment: Ah. The logic is wrong. I'll update the answer - but I'd recommend @Murray McDonald's version. His is cleaner. I gave him an upvote - and if you find his solution useful too, you should too :) (also welcome to Stack Overflow)

Answer (score 0):

First a couple of things. There's a number of "sloppy" coding practices in your example (missing semicolons for instance). While the code may run, it could improve with some jslint help.

So look at the case when x = 1. You decrement x so now x = 0. You then call setTimeout which will wait 1 second and then call your method named startClock. However, setTimeout doesn't block your execution. So immediately after setTimeout is called with x = 0, the code below it is executed where you set x to ' ' (and load your page). Now one second after that code has run, your method is called again due to the timer firing. Since x is now ' ', the top block is skipped and you fall into x == 0 block a second time.